# Behavior near isolated local minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth at its **isolated** local minimum $0$ and $f(0)=0$. Further suppose that there is some $N$ such that in any direction $u$, the $k$-th order directional derivative $f^{(k)}_{u}(0)$ is non-zero for some $k\le N$. Then is there some $\epsilon, \delta>0$ such that $f(x)\ge \epsilon x^N$ for all $x$ with $\|x\|<\delta$?

It seems to me that this should more or less follow from Taylor's theorem, but I am not sure how to exactly work this out. For instance, the answer is negative if $0$ is not assumed to be an isolated minimum, as in the example $f(x,y)=x^2-2xy^2+y^4=(x-y^2)^2$. Do I miss something about multivariate polynomials that's helpful here?

By considering the function $\liminf_{t\to0+} f(tu)/t^N$ on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, I am able to show the existence of some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(tu)\ge\epsilon t^N$ for  all $t\in(0,\delta)$, but the number $\delta$ I obtained possibly depends on $u\in S^{n-1}$ (although $\epsilon$ is uniform). Any idea to drop this potential dependence? Or maybe it is easier to prove it in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: Why "more or less"?

Comment: @Mark, I don't see how it directly follow from Taylor's theorem. The complication comes from the possibility that different directions could have different first non-vanishing directional derivative. If one applies Taylor's theorem for each direction independently, then both $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ could depend on the direction.

Comment: The original statement is not true if $0$ is not an isolated local minimum, such as $f(x,y)=x^2-2xy^2+y^4=(x-y^2)^2$. This also explains the complication in applying Taylor's theorem.